# flutter method checking if item is added to cart in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble with a method that is checking if the item is stored in the firestore database.

```
void add(BuildContext context, CartItem item) {
_items.add(item);

AuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
Map<String, dynamic> cartMap = Map();
_items.forEach((CartItem item) {
  cartMap['title'] = (item.product as Product).title;
  cartMap['name'] = (item.product as Product).name;
});

_instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
_instance!
    .collection('cart')
    .doc(authService.getCurrentUser()) //need to get logged in account's id
    .update({
  'cartProduct': FieldValue.arrayUnion([cartMap])
}).then((value) {
  print(_items.length);
  notifyListeners();
});}
```

The `add` Method adds the item to the firestore in a way like the example image.

[image]

However, after I delete the data using the remove method,

```
 void remove(BuildContext context, CartItem item) {
    _items.remove(item);
    AuthService authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
    Map<String, dynamic> cartMap = Map();
    // _items.forEach((CartItem item) {
    cartMap['title'] = (item.product as Product).title;
    cartMap['name'] = (item.product as Product).name;
    // });
    _instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    _instance!.collection('cart').doc(authService.getCurrentUser()).update({
      'cartProduct': FieldValue.arrayRemove([cartMap]),
    }).then((value) {

      print(_items.length);
      notifyListeners();
    }); }
```

I check if the data is added to the `cartProduct` using `isProductAddedToCart` method and the result is still true. Also, when I print the `_items.length`, it doesn't decrease after I use the `remove` method.

```
  bool isProductAddedToCart(Product? pro) {

    return _items.length >= 0 ? _items.any(
            (CartItem item) => item.product!.title == pro!.title) : false;
  }
```

This is the code where I want to use the `isProductAddedToCart` method.

```
Consumer<CartService>(
            builder: (context, cart, child) {
              Widget renderedButton;
              if (cart.isProductAddedToCart(widget.product) == false) {
                renderedButton = DefaultButton(
                  text: "Participate",
                  press: () {
                    print(cart.isProductAddedToCart(widget.product));
                    cartService.add(context, CartItem(product: widget.product));
                    print(cart.isProductAddedToCart(widget.product));
                  },
                );
              } else {
                renderedButton = DefaultButton(
                  text: "Delete",
                  press: () {
                    print(cart.isProductAddedToCart(widget.product));
                    cartService.remove(
                        context, CartItem(product: widget.product));
                    print(cart.isProductAddedToCart(widget.product));
                  },
                );
              }
              return renderedButton;
```

Comment: Please do not provide the codes as images. Insert them as code snippets to the question.

Comment: Is it actually being updated in the database but doesn't show up in the callback?